# LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't take effect for LibXML.so

Tags: c, perl, ld, libxml2, dynamic-loading

`XML::LibXML` is a Perl library. `LibXML.so` is a part of the library. I'm trying to make `XML::LibXML` use custom built `libxml2`. But providing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't make any difference:

```
$ ldd ./blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.so | grep libxml2
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f66af5e9000)

$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/yuri/_/libxml2/.libs ldd ./blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.so | grep libxml2
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f2d26ae3000)

$ ldd /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/libxml2mod.so | grep libxml2
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f878cbc8000)

$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/yuri/_/libxml2/.libs ldd /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/libxml2mod.so | grep libxml2
    libxml2.so.2 => /home/yuri/_/libxml2/.libs/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f6f8f5d8000)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to handle it? The goal is to make Perl script use custom built `libxml2` (to investigate some issue).

**UPD**

```
$ find /usr/lib -name libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.1.0/lib/lib/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.1.0/lib/lib/libxml2.so.2/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-vmrc/5.5/lib/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-vmrc/5.5/lib/libxml2.so.2/libxml2.so.2

$ find /usr/local/lib -name libxml2.so.2
```

Comment: It's a common error to build libraries with the wrong 32/64 bit status. You must build an image that agrees with your version of Perl, which you can access using `perl -v`. You must also use a version of libxml that is compatible with `XML::LibXML` in every way; ideally the same version.

Comment: It is not uncommon to have multiple `libxml12.so.2` versions installed (especially if you have installed packages containing the file without the use of a package manager). It is worth running a `find` command on `/lib`, `/usr/lib` (distro dependent) and on `/usr/local` to determine if multiple versions exist (or use `locate` if you have `mlocate` installed)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin What has it to do with the issue? It's not that wrong library getting loaded. But that `/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2` getting loaded in spite of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` being set to load other instance of the library. Anyways, I've added output of `find` to the question. FYI, the reason has been found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### tl;dr

`ExtUtils::MakeMaker` hardcodes paths of the shared libraries in the binaries by means of `RPATH` entry in `.dynamic` section. But you can preload the needed library,

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=path/to/custom/libxml2/.libs/libxml2.so.2 ldd ./blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.so
```

or make the loader ignore `RPATH` entry,

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/custom/libxml2/.libs /usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --inhibit-rpath /abs/path/to/LibXML.so /abs/path/to/perl ./1.pl
```

or convert `RPATH` entry into `RUNPATH` one,

```
$ chrpath --convert blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.so
```

or delete `RPATH` entry,

```
$ chrpath --delete blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.so
```

or specify `XMLPREFIX` variable,

```
$ perl Makefile.PL XMLPREFIX=path/to/custom/libxml2/build
```

#### Under the hood

`ExtUtils::Liblist::ext()` takes a list of libraries to be linked with, like `-lxml2 -lz -llzma -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lm -ldl`, and turns them it into [four](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/blob/v7.35_06/lib/ExtUtils/MM_Unix.pm#L1095) or [five](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/blob/v7.35_06/lib/ExtUtils/Liblist.pm#L14) [variables](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/blob/v7.35_06/lib/ExtUtils/Liblist/Kid.pm#L219-L222), that make their way into the generated `Makefile`. One of those is `LD_RUN_PATH`. It contains all the paths where the libraries where found.

`$is_dyna` is true if the library is dynamic (not [ends](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/blob/v7.35_06/lib/ExtUtils/Liblist/Kid.pm#L213) with [`.a`](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/blob/v7.35_06/lib/ExtUtils/Liblist/Kid.pm#L45)). `$is_perl` is true if Perl was not [built](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/blob/v7.35_06/lib/ExtUtils/Liblist/Kid.pm#L214) with [it](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/blob/v7.35_06/lib/ExtUtils/Liblist/Kid.pm#L44), and `%ld_run_path_seen` is to not duplicate values in `LD_RUN_PATH`.

The part that [calculates](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/blob/v7.35_06/lib/ExtUtils/MM_Any.pm#L2437) `LD_RUN_PATH`, that generates part of the Makefile with the [variable](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/blob/v7.35_06/lib/ExtUtils/MM_Unix.pm#L382-L387), and the part that passes it to the [linker](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/blob/v7.35_06/lib/ExtUtils/MM_Unix.pm#L1060-L1070).

#### Consequences

`LD_RUN_PATH` and in its turn `RPATH` entry in the binary make the loader search for libraries (at runtime) in the directories where they where found (at compile time).

> -rpath=dir
>   **Add a directory to the runtime library search path.** This is used when linking an ELF executable with shared objects. All -rpath arguments are concatenated and passed to the runtime linker, which uses them to locate shared objects at runtime. The -rpath option is also used when locating shared objects which are needed by shared objects explicitly included in the link; see the description of the -rpath-link option. **If -rpath is not used when linking an ELF executable, the contents of the environment variable "LD_RUN_PATH" will be used if it is defined.**

https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/core/binutils/ld.1.en

> If a shared object dependency does not contain a slash, then it is searched for in the following order:
>
> o Using the directories specified in the **DT_RPATH** dynamic section attribute of the binary if present and DT_RUNPATH attribute does not exist. Use of DT_RPATH is deprecated.
>
> o Using the environment variable **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**, unless the executable is being run in secure-execution mode (see below), in which case this variable is ignored.

https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/core/man-pages/ld.so.8.en

```
$ perl Makefile.PL
$ make
```

Result,

```
$ readelf --dynamic ./blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.so | grep RPATH
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [/usr/lib]

$ objdump -x ./blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.so | egrep RPATH
  RPATH                /usr/lib

$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/custom/libxml2/.libs ldd ./blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.so | grep libxml2
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f6cfabb2000)
```

`--dynamic` - display contents of the `.dynamic` section, `-x` - display all headers.

#### Solution

One way to remedy this is to preload needed instance of `libxml2`,

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=path/to/custom/libxml2/.libs/libxml2.so.2 ldd ./blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.so | grep libxml2
    path/to/custom/libxml2/build/lib/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fe183aeb000)
```

Another is to tell `Makefile.PL` search for `libxml2` in the desired location (at compile time).

```
$ perl Makefile.PL XMLPREFIX=path/to/custom/libxml2/build
$ make
```

Result,

```
$ readelf --dynamic ./blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.so | grep RPATH
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [path/to/custom/libxml2/build/lib:/usr/lib]

$ objdump -x ./blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.so | egrep RPATH
  RPATH                path/to/custom/libxml2/build/lib:/usr/lib

$ ldd ./blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.so | grep libxml2
    libxml2.so.2 => path/to/custom/libxml2/build/lib/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fe183aeb000)
```

#### On a side note

Should you care to debug `XML::LibXML`, you can run make with `OPTIMIZE` variable (add `-B` to make make rebuild everything in case the library has already been built),

```
$ make OPTIMIZE='-g3 -O0'
```

There's also `-O2`, and no `-g` in `LDDLFLAGS`, but not sure if that matters much.

Alternatively, `WriteMakeFile` takes `OPTIMIZE` parameter, so you can add a line [here](https://github.com/shlomif/perl-XML-LibXML/blob/XML-LibXML-2.0132/Makefile.PL#L462),

```
'OPTIMIZE' => '-g3 -O0'
```

Or you can add the variable [here](https://github.com/shlomif/perl-XML-LibXML/blob/XML-LibXML-2.0132/Makefile.PL#L107), and pass it to `Makefile.PL`,

```
$ perl Makefile.PL OPTIMIZE='-g3 -O0'
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and is likely to be deleted. It appears to be an attempt to add further information to the question. Please use the [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52234414/edit) link beneath the tags on your question to alter its content.

Comment: @Borodin How come it's not an answer? It explains why `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't work, and provides a way to overcome it. Please explain what exactly is wrong with my answer.

Comment: I guess I owe you an apology. I read it quite carefully and it seemed to be a long list of things that don't work. I still don't see quite where the solution is, and I think you need to make sure that the English language part of your question explains what you are trying to say, as code and quotations are generally seen as citations.

Comment: @Borodin Is it any better?

Comment: No, not really. All you seem to have done is rename the blocks with bold `**` markup. You should be using *header* markup anyway, and I shouldn't have to play *find the difference* to discover your solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you install your custom built version of libxml in `/usr/local/lib`, I think the XML::LibXML module should load the custom one rather than the one in `/usr/lib` (Assuming you have sudoers or root permission to install it).

I'm not sure why Python seems to use a different lookup path for libraries than Perl does, though. Maybe the full path to libxml library is hardcoded in XML::LibXML's LibXML.so? If the XML::LibXML module was linked with -l/usr/lib/libxml2.so instead of -lxml2 that would be the problem.

Comment: You were close, `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` does hardcode paths to the libraries in the binaries. But by means of `RPATH` entry in `.dynamic` section.